# extending MongoRepository

Tags: spring, mongodb, maven

I'm new to spring and confused as to how autowiring works on an interface that extends MongoRepository

Here is the code:

*App.java*

```
package com.db.mongo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;


@SpringBootApplication
public class App implements CommandLineRunner
{
    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository repository;

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }

    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        repository.deleteAll();
        repository.save(new Customer("Alice", "Smith"));
        repository.save(new Customer("Bob", "Smith"));

        System.out.println("Customers found with findAll():");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------");
        for (Customer customer : repository.findAll()) {
            System.out.println(customer);
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Customer found with findByFirstName('Alice'):");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        System.out.println(repository.findByFirstName("Alice"));

        System.out.println("Customers found with findByLastName('Smith'):");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        for (Customer customer : repository.findByLastName("Smith")) {
            System.out.println(customer);
        }
    }
}
```

*CustomerRepository*

```
package com.db.mongo;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

public interface CustomerRepository extends MongoRepository  {

     public Customer findByFirstName(String firstName);
        public List<Customer> findByLastName(String lastName);
}
```

*Customer.java*

```
package com.db.mongo;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

public class Customer {
    @Id
    public String id;

    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;

    public Customer() {}

    public Customer(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
                "Customer[id=%s, firstName='%s', lastName='%s']",
                id, firstName, lastName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately [questions asking for: books, libraries, tutorials, tools, or other off-site resource are off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and should be closed. Stack Overflow is a [Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) website for specific programming questions.

Comment: What exactly is confusing?

Comment: The Customer class does not implement the CustomerRepository interface but the reference variable of CustomerRepository interface calls the methods(` findByFirstName()` & ` findBylastName() `). How is it actually implemented?

Comment: @SaiKrishnan For your repository interface be aware of entity class, you should do "..extends MongoRepository<Customer, String>", that's how it ties repository and entity. Please see docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/2.2.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#mongo-repo-usage

Answer (score 0):

if you are using spring data mongodb.It has the capability to create the query which are in your domain. The CrudRepository provides sophisticated CRUD functionality for the entity class that is being managed.for more details read [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/2.1.0.M3/reference/html/)